# Demoting Server Login/DB User Permissions to SELECT, View Definitions, Exec Stored Procs and use functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, server, permissions

I am working though a change in permissions so that when in production, a user may only view definitions, select tables, execute stored procedures, and use functions. Essentially any modifications to objects, or data is to be denied.

The user is currently a sysadmin with `DENYDATAWRITER` role applied. What else should be applied to match these permissions?

I am fairly new to DB security so any help is greatly appreciated. This is for SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: GRAN/REVOKE/DENY permissions do not apply in this case because permissions on sysadmin role members are not checked. Consider removing the sysadmin role and instead adding the user to the needed database as a db_datareader role member.

Comment: This makes sense, but with datareader we are unable to execute any stored procs

Comment: For all procs, you can grant execute at the database level. e.g. `USE YourDatabase;GRANT EXECUTE ON DATABASE::tempdb TO <your-user-or-role>`

Answer (score 1):

Solution used was to create new role, which gave select, connect, execute and view definition permission, and assign user to this in combination with db_denydatawriter.

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

DENY priority level is higher than normal, so I think you can give the authorization of db_OWNER and db_DENYDATAWRITER together.

Answer (score 0):

The sysadmin role plus DENYDATAWRITER, has higher permissions than what you have listed.

I'd suggest DATAREADER and GRANT EXECUTE.